# Limit the number of images that can be uploaded to a Product Gallery, have error "File is empty"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have vendor category of users and I wanna limit the number of images that can be uploaded to a Product Gallery for them without any plugin. I tried [this variant](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/how-can-you-limit-the-number-of-images-videos-that-can-be-uploaded-to-a-wordpr?answertab=active#tab-top), but it didn't helped me.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');
function limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file)
{
    global $current_user;
    if (get_post_type() == 'vendor' && in_array('vendor', $current_user->roles)) {
        if ($file['type'] == 'application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
            $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
            if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error'] != 0) {
                $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
                return $file;
            } else {
                $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
            }
        }
        if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
            if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}")) > 4)
                $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than five (5) image.";
        }
        return $file;
    }
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: please provide code samples of things you have tried

Comment: Yea, sorry. I have added sample of code.

Comment: It is working but it gives an error: "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini."
And it is not clear what happened. I mean for user.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of problem related to this error. I think it's due to some permissions related to image management interface. I resolved using [Role Editor Plugin](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and enabling "edit_published_posts" (under core) to user roles that have this problem (i.e. vendor).  I hope this can help.